# "Install the PyCoral library" instructions not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-coral

#### Description

Hey, firstly I just want to note I've tried following numerous guides and nothing appears to work.

Setup:
Intel NUC, NUC11PAHi7 32GB+1TB
Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS
Linux ubuntu-whytings 5.15.0-75-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 6 23:10:23 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've tried following the following:
https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#2-install-the-pycoral-library

When I get to running command:
`sudo apt-get install python3-pycoral`

I get the following error:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python3-pycoral :
> Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to
> be installed
> Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
> packages.

I can't find a way to get around this problem.

Many Thanks

Comment: > Note: PyCoral currently supports Python 3.6 through 3.9. If your default version is something else, we suggest you install Python 3.9 with pyenv.

Comment: I currently have Python 3.10.6 installed. Can you advise me on the commands required to get a version of python that will work with PyCoral?

Comment: This guide looks to work to get pyenv installed:

https://brain2life.hashnode.dev/how-to-install-pyenv-python-version-manager-on-ubuntu-2004

However, I still can't install python3-pycoral. Do I need to run it in a certain way?

Comment: I'm still stuck. Does anyone have a full guide on getting onto the right python version and running the required commands afterwards to successfully run python3-pycoral